# finite solvable groups whose commutator subgroup is nilpotent

Tags: finite-groups, lie-algebras

The finite solvable groups G  whose commutator subgroup G' is nilpotent,
look interesting to me  (in view of the easy structure of finite nilpotent groups and the resemblance with solvable Lie algebras in char. 0). Let me call such groups perfectly solvable. Note that the finite supersolvable groups (groups with cyclic normal series) are perfectly solvable.

Have such groups been studied in Literature ?
Thank you.

Comment: These are precisely the finite groups $G$ such that $G/F(G)$ is Abelian. Additionally, $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(F(G))$ for such a group. I'm not sure what more one can expect to say.

Comment: I have no idea if these have actually been studied. One thing is that they satisfy the Taketa inequality, as I explain at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272849/if-a-finite-group-g-is-solvable-is-g-g-nilpotent/

Comment: Another characterization is that they are the groups $G$ such that $G/\Phi(G)$ is Metabelian.

Comment: Thank you. You may check my Conjecture/Question  at
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253729/finite-homomorphic-images-of-infinite-products-of-finite-solvable-groups

Comment: Groups with a nilpotent derived subgroup are called "nilpotent-by-abelian". @GeoffRobinson I'm not sure everybody knows your notation ($F(G)$, $\Phi(G)$) by heart. I don't.

Comment: @YCor: $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup (unique largest normal nilpotent subgroup); $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup (intersection of maximal subgroups).

Comment: @YCor: I can't speak for infinite group-theorists, but I think that all finite group theorists (who have done a graduate course including finite group theory) would be familiar with $F(G)$ and $\Phi(G).$ In any case, Arturo Magidin's explanation is accurate.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson corollary of our two comments: everybody is not a finite group theorist (at least according to your definition) Anyway, I haven't done a graduate course in infinite group theory either...

Comment: I do not consider it unreasonable to use standard group theoretic notation in a comment on a question with a finite groups tag.

Comment: @NazihNahlus : My first comment above points out that they are precisely the groups with $G/F(G)$ Abelian. There are groups of Fitting  length $2$ which do not have that property.