# Finite Homomorphic images of infinite products of finite solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups

I conjecture that:
Every Finite Homomorphic image of an infinite (with arbitrary cardinality) product   of finite solvable groups is solvable -- or at least Not a simple (non-abelian) group.

I can see this conjecture in some cases.
but the general case seems very complicated.

Question:  Has this problem been investigated ?
Thank you.

Edit-- Moreover, I also conjecture that Every Finite Homomorphic image of an INFINITE  product G = \prod G_i of finite simple (non-abelian) groups {G_i},  is a product of finite simple groups each of which is isomorphic to some G_i.

Y Cor has kindly outlined the proof of my 2 conjectures (in comments below) via the Nikolov-Segal Theorem (Annals of Math., 2007). Moreover, Yilong Yang has 
just found another proof (of my 2nd conjecture) by using his covering properties of finite groups (introduced in his publication in 2016).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct: every finite quotient is solvable. Indeed let $G$ be your product of finite solvable groups. Let $p:G\to F$ be a (possibly non-continuous) surjective homomorphism to a finite group $F$. Lift $F$ to a finite subset $\tilde{F}$, and let $H$ be the closed subgroup generated by $\tilde{F}$. Then by the Nikolov-Segal theorem, the restriction of $p$ to $H$ is continuous. But as a closed subgroup of $G$, $H$ is a projective limit of finite solvable groups. So all its quotients by open subgroups are finite solvable groups.

More generally, this shows that

> any abstract finite quotient of a profinite group $G$ is isomorphic to some $H/K$ where $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ and $K$ an open normal subgroup of $H$.

(In the particular case when $G$ is pro-$p$ for some prime $p$, this appeals to a much older theorem of Serre instead of Nikolov-Segal.)

---

(Edit, to answer a question in a comment.) The previous actually shows a slightly stronger statement:

> (1) if $G$ is a profinite group and $F$ is a finite quotient of $G$, then there exists a t.f.g. closed subgroup $M$ of $G$ such that for every t.f.g. closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $M$, $F$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $H$ by some closed normal subgroup.

[t.f.g. means topologically finitely generated, meaning having a dense finitely generated subgroup]

Now I claim that

> (2) if $G$ is a product $\prod S_i$ of finite simple groups (possibly abelian), then every t.f.g. closed subgroup of $G$ is contained in a t.f.g. closed subgroup that is a product of finite simple groups.

If we combine (1) and (2), we deduce that

> in an arbitrary product of finite simple groups $\prod_{i\in I}S_i$, every abstract finite quotient is isomorphic to some finite product $\prod_{j\in J}S_j$

(although it's not always given by the obvious projection!).

Actually while (1) follows from the Nikolov-Segal theorem (every finite index subgroup is open, in a t.f.g. profinite group), the particular case of the Nikolov-Segal theorem for products of finite simple group was proved by Saxl and Wilson, namely: if $(S_n)$ is a sequence of finite simple groups and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|S_n|=\infty$, then every finite index subgroup in $\prod S_n$ is open. (J. Saxl and J. S. Wilson, A note on powers in simple groups, Math. Proc. Cambridge Phil.
Soc. 122 (1997), 91-94.)

Checking (2) is quite elementary, modulo the fact that finite simple groups have a bounded generating rank, namely every finite simple group is generated by 2 elements, which relies on classification. Gather together all isomorphic simple groups in the product, to write $G=\prod_S G_S$, where each $G_S\simeq S^{I_S}$, and $S$ ranges over non-isomorphic finite simple groups. Let $L$ be a t.f.g. closed subgroup of $G$; so $L$ has a dense subgroup generated by $d$ elements for some $d$. Let $L_S$ be its projection in $S^{I_S}$; it is generated by $d$ elements. Let $M_S$ be the subgroup of $S^{I_S}$ generated by $L_S$ and the diagonal; it is generated by $\le d+2$ elements (because any finite simple group is generated by 2 elements). Also, every finitely generated subgroup of $S^{I_S}$ containing the diagonal is isomorphic to $S^k$ for some $k$. So if we choose a family of $d+2$ elements in $\prod M_S$ whose $S$-component generates $M_S$, we obtain a generating subset for a dense subgroup of $\prod M_S$, and $M_S$ is a product of finite simple groups. This proves (2).

Comment: Wow.  It looks  Great!. 
I need to check carefully the Nikolov-Segal Theorem.

Question: Are you taking the pro-discrete topology on G (that is, the topology obtained by putting the discrete topology on each G_i) ?.

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group

Comment: Thanks. Do Nikolov-Segal paper(s)  show  explicitly the statement of the above result & similar results in profinite groups ?
 like what if each G_i is a finite simple group, then One would expect a finite homomorphic image of G =\prod G_i   to be a product of simple groups each is isomorphic to some G_i.
Are you referring to their paper in 2012 ?
Big THANK you.

Comment: The explicit Nikolov-Segal statement (the one I refer to) is that any homomorphism from a profinite group with a dense finitely generated subgroup, to a finite group, is continuous. Equivalently, in such a group, all finite index subgroups are open. It's a 2007 paper in Annals of Math.

Comment: Your question whether every quotient of a product of finite simple groups is is isomorphic to a quotient by a closed normal subgroup has a positive answer. The reason is that every finite subset of a product of simple groups is contained in a closed subgroup that has a finitely generated dense subgroup and itself is isomorphic to a product of simple groups (this latter fact can be checked by hand, once we know that each simple finite group is 2-generated). Then one uses my argument which shows more precisely that all large enough $H$ admit the given group as quotient.

Comment: In the last line of (1) above, I think you meant $H$ instead of $G$. In any case, $H$ isn't mentioned in the conclusion.

Comment: @HJRW thanks! it's a bad typo because the conclusion that $F$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$ by a closed normal subgroup would be tempting. But I think there are (nontrivial) counterexamples.

Comment: @Y Cor.  Big Thank you. The case of simple groups was solved recently by Yilong Yang by using the results of his paper in J.Group Theory. 2) At present, Yilong and myself are  writing a joint paper on such questions. 

3) My self & Yilong like to invite you to join us as a 3rd author in our present paper on such questions & related questions
4) Can you please email me at nahlus@aub.edu.lb.   ManyThanks.

Comment: @ Y. Cor.  I guess we may be able to skip step 2 (thus avoiding the very deep theorem on 2 generators of simple groups) and work directly on the more general situation of inverse-limits of finite products of (non-abelian) finite simple groups. (Here the directed inverse system is assumed to be surjective). This is plausible by the uniquemess of the Remak-Schmidth decompositions of such groups.

Comment: Yes one can avoid this 2-generated stuff by appealing directly to the Saxl-Wilson theorem (which anyway also relies on the classification of finite simple group).

Comment: @  Y.Cor,   Thank you.  AGAIN:   myself and Yilong Yang, have already invited you above  to be a 3rd author in our present paper on such questions & related ones on inverse limits, quasisimple, ..etc.    
Are you interested ?

Comment: Thanks Nazih, but I'm happy to contribute through MathOverflow and not more. Good luck!

Comment: @Y. Cor.  Many Many Thanks to you . But at least we need to greatly thank you in acknowledgments.  
Shall  we say Y.Cor of MathOVerflow ???

Comment: @ Y. Cor.  I just checked that you are in the top
0.17 % this quarter in MathOverflow.  
Congratulations.  WOW. Amazing!

Comment: If you click YCor you get my public profile, which includes a link to my web page so that you can have my real name there, in case you need to quote me.

Comment: No, it's not true. The hypothesis in Saxl-Wilson is necessary: if $S$ is a simple group and $I$ is infinite, then there is a non-continuous surjective homomorphism from $S^I$ to $S$ (e.g., given as limit along an ultraproduct). In my argument I don't "delete" factors. The above homomorphism is trivial in restriction to any factor. But it's nontrivial, say, on the diagonal.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Btw, George Bergman has already "generalized" the work of Serre to finite dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras at  https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/pro-np2.pdf . Moreover, we both answered the analogous conjectures for Lie algebras over infinite fields (of char not 2, 3) at https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/prod_Lie1.pdf

Comment: @Y Cor,  I do not see clearly  the  last step in your proof that "we can choose a family of d+2 elements in \prod M_S    whose S-component generates M_S,  we obtain a generating subset for a dense subgroup of \prod M_S". 


It seems to boil down to every finite product of finite simple groups is generated by 2 elements which is not clear at all.
Can you please explain!

Comment: No it does not boil down to the 2-generated fact, which was used to produce this family of $d+2$ elements. Choosing such a family for all $S$ produces a subgroup $P$ of $\prod_SM_S$ whose projection on $M_S\simeq S^{k_S}$ is surjective for all $S$. So I'm using the fact that this forces $P$ to be dense. This is quite elementary: it boils down to the case of a finite product. (It's a generalization of the elementary fact that if $S,T$ are non isomorphic simple groups, then the only subgroup of $S\times T$ whose both projections to $S$ and $T$ are surjective, is equal to $S\times T$.)

Comment: @ Y Cor.   Thank you very much.
I was esp. worried about  the factors S^{k_S} when k_S > 1.
But you have the projection of the subgroup  P above is surjective on every  M_S or S^{k_S).  So  in the generalization of the elementary fact  (you mentioned above) to the case of n factors while allowing  isomorphic factors,  the subdirect product has been augmented with all S^{k_S} to get the desired 'whole" group.

Comment: To be more precise (in my last comment),   the last line should be:
[the subdirect product  subgroup A  (in a finite product  G of finite simple groups) has the additional property that its canonical projections on each S^{k_S} is surjective in order to get A=G.]

Comment: @ Y. Cor.   Again, Thank you very much Yves for your help.


In fact, I found a slight variation of  your proof that avoids the 2-generation theorem (such proof was  sent to you by email ) which I will post as a comment  on MathOF in few weeks. Recall that Yilong Yang  has found another proof using  the covering properties of finite groups introduced by his paper in 2016.